# How can I account for ambigious column name when testing ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I am working on assisting with a gem [activerecord-sqlserver-adapter](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/713) to finish it's tests for Rails 5.2.3.  I'm trying to understand the ActiveRecord test below (and [here](https://rubydocs.org/d/rails-5-2-3/classes/RelationTest.html#method-i-test_pluck_with_from_includes_quoted_original_table_name)).

```
# File activerecord/test/cases/relations_test.rb
def test_pluck_with_from_includes_quoted_original_table_name
  relation = Comment.joins(:post).order(:id)
  subquery = Comment.from("#{Comment.quoted_table_name} /*! USE INDEX (PRIMARY) */").joins(:post).order(:id)
  assert_equal relation.pluck(:id), subquery.pluck(:id)
end
```

When I run the test currently I get the following error.

```
Error:
RelationTest#test_pluck_with_from_includes_quoted_original_table_name_coerced:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Ambiguous column name 'id'.: SELECT [id] FROM [comments] /*! USE INDEX (PRIMARY) */ LEFT OUTER JOIN [posts] ON [posts].[id] = [comments].[post_id]  ORDER BY [id] ASC

bin/rails test mnt/c/Users/mcdonaldd/Documents/open_source/sqlserver-main/test/cases/coerced_tests.rb:763
```

To my knowledge I would expect this as I've not specified which table the "id" column should come from... however I'm guessing the solution to building a passing test would not be to change it to...

```
assert_equal relation.pluck(:id), subquery.pluck('posts.id')
```

Could anyone give me some understanding as to how the above line in it's original form from the documentation should be working in this context without passing in the specific table name as well?

Comment: This looks like a bug / shortcoming in the sql server adapter. Pg creates `SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" /*! USE INDEX (PRIMARY) */ INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."id" = "comments"."post_id" ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT $1`. But then again thats a real database... :)

Comment: @max Ahh this may be the issue.  I can try and track that down and add it.  How does it select which :id to pluck even with the comments/posts prefixes?  Does it just choose the first one in the select?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but `Comment.pluck(:id)` refers to the model your calling it on. The pg adapter is smart enough to be specific and use `comments.id` instead of just `id` which would be ambiguous. In this case maybe you could pass a string to make it explicit. `.pluck('comments.id')` or whatever crazy syntax SQL Server uses to refer to columns.

Comment: @max, my apologies.  So what I'm asking is when `subquery.pluck(:id)` is executed above for Pg, does it use `Comment.id` because subquery originated from `Comment`?  Even though it's joining to :post which also has an id column.  Thanks!

Comment: `.joins(:posts)` does not automatically change the recipient to Post. Rather it just adds a join clause to the query. If you want to select or pluck columns from the joined table you need to specify the table. `.pluck('comments.id', 'posts.id')` would for example give you an array of `[comment.id, post.id]`.

Comment: I think on pretty much every other adapter `pluck(:id, 'posts.id')` or `select(:id, 'posts.id')` would generate non-ambiguous sql.